# Where does "emphasis mine" go in a quotation?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, writing-style

I have often seen the term *emphasis mine* used whenever an author wishes to denote that emphasis in a given quotation originates from said author rather than from the original source.

**What is the proper place for this phrase?**

One possibility is immediately following the emphatic text, inside the quotation. But, see next question...

**What if there are multiple emphatic sections marked within the quote?**

If "emphasis mine" comes immediately after each phrase, it would end up repeated two or more times, which seems a bit messy. In this case, would it be OK to place "emphasis mine" at the end of the quotation? If so, should it be inside or outside?

**How should the phrase "emphasis mine" be set off?**

I believe I have seen parentheses () or brackets [], though brackets are also used to indicate words added by the one using the quotation.

Comment: This rule of consistency, then, strongly suggests that, if there are many instances of added _italics_, they probably are best put at the end of a short quotation, at the end of each paragraph in a multi-paragraph quotation, at the end of a line in a poem, at the end of a stanza in a song. It's  also reasonable & not uncommon to say "**[Italics added]**".

Answer (score 19):

[Wikipedia's Manual of Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Quotations), similar to most other style manuals, says:

> Do not put quotations in italics unless the material would otherwise call for italics, such as for emphasis and the use of non-English words. Indicate whether italics were used in the original text or whether they were added later. For example, directly from the [Manual of Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style#Italics_within_quotations):
>
> "Now cracks a noble heart. Good night sweet prince: And *flights of angels* sing thee to thy rest." [emphasis added]

Comment: Yes - I use *(italics mine)* on ELU because I don't feel the need to be particularly "formal" here, but in many real-world contexts *[emphasis added]* is obviously much more appropriate. Plus of course, formal contexts often use *square* brackets for "extraneous material" in the vicinity of verbatim quoted material.

Comment: Yes, and in those real-world contexts, there's usually a required style manual with specific rules about all this clerical stuff: it ain't English, that's for sure. And when there isn't, it's best to use the style manual you prefer: the _Chicago Manual of Style_ is as good a choice as any general style manual, and the _APA Style Manual_ is as bad a choice as anyone could ever make. Both judgments strictly IMHO.

Answer (score 8):

What I found most subtle among the different methods I've seen was to put it right between the introductory text and the quotation itself, between parentheses. Like so (emphasis mine):

> **Whatever**.

In this way, it's easy for the reader not to focus on that if he doesn't care, and to be aware of it when actually reading the quotation if he does.

I wouldn't call that a rule, but I don't think there's much more but good practices adressing this question either.

---

In French¹, I stumbled on the interesting other technique of embedding this information in the surrounding text. Translating² :

> […] : « [book extract] Maintenant, […], *blaguons*… »³
>
> Balzac emphasised that, then to comment : “[…] dazed, as it could have been *hearing an angel blaspheming*.” *We* emphasized that.

**The author highlights Balzac's comment, but I'm the one who highlights the way he inserts it in the text.**

¹ in which I don't see many such notices, because emphasis is seldom added, I reckon.
² It's about the etymology of *“blague”* (→*blaguons*), hence the importance of that word being emphasized by the original author.
³ Italics for being foreign ommited for the sake of it all.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule-of-thumb, place "(emphasis mine)" immediately **after** the quotation.

"As for you, you were dead in your *transgressions* and sins" (Eph. 2:1, emphasis mine).  ([Bowland](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=EpQOXiugjEIC&pg=PA54&dq=%22emphasis%20mine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PVyXUIKDN5CyrAfb5oCYCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22emphasis%20mine%22&f=false))
Not: "*Uneasy* (emphasis mine) feelings, feelings of *compassion* ... (emphasis mine)"

Where there are many sections that you emphasized and probably extended over several sentences, or even paragraphs, you can, **alternately**, place it at the **beginning** of the quote, preferably with a terminal colon. 
"(emphasis mine:) *Uneasy* feelings, feelings of *compassion* ... "

When there's already an emphasized part within the quote, place "(emphasis mine)" immediately **after the part that you have emphasized**.

"According to the pragmatic view, the proper goal of science is to *augment* and *order* (emphasis mine) our experience." ([Cory](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=vrgeEfLm-4cC&pg=PA223&dq=%22emphasis%20mine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=z16XULepDYzjrAfCyYDADA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22emphasis%20mine%22&f=false)) -- The word 'augment' was already in italics in the original; 'order' is being emphasized by you.

The most common practice seems to enclose the phrase "emphasis mine" in simple **parentheses**: "(emphasis mine)" -- where there's a possibility of ambiguity, you can switch to square braces, "[]". However, one needs to be **consistent** throughout in the convention.

Comment: I find this interrupts the thought too much.